# Making requests to many urls via multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a list of relative urls-`PostLink` and a `base_url`. I made requests to every url via a `for loop`. It works well and takes around six minutes.

```
import requests
bowl = requests.get('http://www.aaronsw.com/weblog/fullarchive')
soup = BeautifulSoup(bowl.text, 'html.parser')
PostLink = soup.body.find_all('a', href = True)
PostLink = [i['href'] for i in PostLink][2:]
baseurl = 'http://www.aaronsw.com/weblog/'
bowls = [requests.get(baseurl + i) for i in PostLink]
```

Now I think this job is I/O intensive, I hope to speed up crawling through multithreading.

I have tried with

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(6)
res = []
for i in PostLink:
    future = pool.submit(requests.get, (baseurl + i))
    res.append(future.result())
```

I think what I did is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that multiprocesses a list of items and executes `your_function` in parallel against every item in the list

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def multi_processor(function_name):

    file_list = []

    # Test, put 6 strings in the list so your_function should run six times with 6 processors in parallel (assuming your CPU has that many cores)
    file_list.append("test1")
    file_list.append("test2")
    file_list.append("test3")
    file_list.append("test4")
    file_list.append("test5")
    file_list.append("test6")

    # Use max number of system processors - 1
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count()-1)
    pool.daemon = True

    results = {}
    # for every  file in the file list, start a new process
    for each_file in file_list:
        results[each_file] = pool.apply_async(function_name, args=("arg1", "arg2"))

    # Wait for all processes to finish before proceeding
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Results and any errors are returned
    return {your_function: result.get() for your_function, result in results.items()}


def your_function(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        print("put your stuff in this function")
        your_results = ""
        return your_results
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_results = multi_processor(your_function)
    print(some_results)
```

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894487/python-threading-or-multiprocessing-for-web-crawler, I learn that better to use multithreading in this case.

Comment: Sry man, I've never used multithreading so I don't have any snippets for it. Based on that URL you provided, I don't think the I/O vs CPU intensive is going to matter that much in your case. If serial processing takes 6 minutes, I'd guess the difference between multithreading and processing isn't much. Multithreading is not memory safe meaning that memory references between the threads can collide. Multiprocessing doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It takes around 54 seconds using `multiprocessing`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(6) as p:
    bowls = p.map(requests.get, [baseurl+i for i in PostLink])
```

While using `mutithreading` can also speed up the task.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
startt = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    bowls = executor.map(requests.get, [baseurl+i for i in PostLink])
time.time()-startt
```