# Writing to SQLite DB in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, concurrent.futures

A disclaimer that I'm a concurrency/parallelism novice (still learning the fundamentals) and thanks in advance.

I want to:

1. pull data from an API
2. write it to a file
3. set a flag in a SQLite database so I don't pull it again

**Current Single Threaded Process**

My basic workflow is:

```
import sqlite3, requests, tqdm, os, gzip
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry
DB = './my_db.sqlite3'

@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=9, period=1)
def download(job, conn):
    pk, url, is_downloaded = job
    res = requests.get(url)
    filename = BASE_DIR+f'/{pk}.txt.gz'
    if res.status_code == 200:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True) 
        with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(res.content)
        update_db(pk, conn)
    else:
        raise Exception('crawl error')

def update_db(pk, conn):
    with conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('''update my_table set is_downloaded = 1 where id = ?;''', (pk,))
        conn.commit()
    return

conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(jobs)) as progress:
      for job in jobs: 
        download(job, conn)
        progress.update()
conn.close()
```

This runs slowly presumably due to the IO of the API and database writes; I *hope* this could be speed up through some sort of concurrency. I have questions about the theory/wisdom of this as well as the implementation.

**The implementation question**

I tried to implement this using the `futures` package:

```
import concurrent.futures

# Using same download and update_db funcs as above
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
futures = []
with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(jobs)) as progress:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as exe:
        for job in jobs:
            f = exe.submit(download, job, conn)
            futures.append(f)
            f.add_done_callback(lambda x: progress.update()) 

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            if f.exception():
                raise Exception(f.exception())
```

When I implemented this without the DB write, it *was* notably faster, which was reassuring. However, when I added in the DB write, it threw an exception: `Exception: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 4336387456 and this is thread id 6202470400.`

What's the proper way to write to a DB in a multithreaded app like this? I read that SQLite [can support](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) multithreading, but don't feel knowledgable enough to apply what this means: "provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads."

**The Theory question**

I'm still confused by the differences in multithreading vs multiprocessing, especially in context of Python's GIL and my use case, presumably which is network- and disk- I/O heavy. I believe multithreading is the [right approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894487/python-threading-or-multiprocessing-for-web-crawler), and am seeking confirmation. Is what I am doing the *right* approach?

I read that [threads share the same memory space](https://towardsdatascience.com/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3afeb73e105f), while processes do not. If this is the case, why do I get an error from my SQLite client saying `Exception: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 4336387456 and this is thread id 6202470400.`?

Comment: Each thread needs their own connection to the database; sqlite is _not_ a high concurrency database platform so this may slow it down.  Alternatively you might use one thread to manage database objects, and farm work out to other threads.

Comment: I don’t feel authoritive enough to make a full answer, but SQLITE database connection objects are generally “thread-safe”, therefore cannot be used in multiple threads at the same time.   There’s a wealth of information here: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html .  I believe python has it configured it in Multi-Thread mode, and the python bindings check for that.